# Indefinite integral $\int xe^x (x+1)^{-2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I was solving a differential equation by reduction of order, and was required to evaluate the indefinite integral

$$I=\int \frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}dx.$$

The only method that came to mind was inspection, i.e. recognizing that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^x}{x+1} = \frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}.$$

I would not trust myself to recognize this under the pressure of a test or exam, so is it possible to evaluate $I$ by substitution, parts, or some other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nice trick is to write $\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$ as $\frac{(x+1)-1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(x+1)}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, then apply integration by parts:

$$ \int \frac{e^x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx = -\frac{e^x}{1+x}+\int \frac{e^x}{(1+x)}\,dx.$$

Comment: To some extent it's not so tricky, because it's just some sort of partial fraction decomposition :)

Answer (score 6):

Notice  $$\int \frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}\ dx $$ $$=\int \frac{(x+1-1)e^x}{(x+1)^2}\ dx $$
$$=\int e^x\left( \frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)\ dx $$
$$=\int e^x\left( \frac{1}{(x+1)}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)\ dx $$
let $x+1=t\implies dx=dt$
$$=\int e^{t-1}\left( \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\ dx $$
$$=\frac{1}{e} \int e^{t}\left( \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\ dx $$
Using $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx=e^xf(x)+C$ 
$$=\frac{e^{t}}{e}\frac{1}{t}+C $$
$$=\frac{e^{t-1}}{t}+C $$
$$=e^{x}\frac{1}{x+1}+C $$

Comment: Nice solution. What I like about this trick is that it's really effective at showing how the integral has no elementary expression for $x + a$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

$\int\dfrac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}dx$

$=-\int xe^x~d\left(\dfrac{1}{x+1}\right)$

$=-\dfrac{xe^x}{x+1}+\int\dfrac{1}{x+1}d(xe^x)$

$=-\dfrac{xe^x}{x+1}+\int\dfrac{(x+1)e^x}{x+1}dx$

$=-\dfrac{xe^x}{x+1}+\int e^x~dx$

$=-\dfrac{xe^x}{x+1}+e^x+C$

$=\dfrac{(x+1)e^x-xe^x}{x+1}+C$

$=\dfrac{e^x}{x+1}+C$